# Python - Pandas Groupby and filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this as a csv working in pandas- first ten rows:

A simplified df as follows:

```
        permno    price            mv  yearmonth
1752     10057  18.1250  7.898875e+04     198301
4732     10137  23.7500  1.130191e+06     198301
6144     10153   9.7500  1.226550e+05     198302
7869     10225  45.8750  2.530740e+06     198302
8267     10233  57.6250  1.670894e+06     198303
8692     10241  30.8750  5.742132e+06     198303
```

Would like to group by yearmonth and sorting according to mv into 5 groups by separating into 5 quantile in each yearmonth to get the expected result:

```
yearmonth:198301, quantile:quantile(0.2)
        permno    price            mv  yearmonth
1752     10057  18.1250  7.898875e+04     198301
yearmonth:198301, quantile:quantile(0.4)
4732     10137  23.7500  1.130191e+06     198301
yearmonth:198302, quantile:quantile(0.2)
        permno    price            mv  yearmonth
6144     10057   9.7500  1.226550e+05     198302
yearmonth:198302, quantile:quantile(0.4)
        permno    price            mv  yearmonth
7869     10137  45.8750  2.530740e+06     198302
yearmonth:198303, quantile:quantile(0.2)
        permno    price            mv  yearmonth
8267     10057  57.6250  1.670894e+06     198303
yearmonth:198303, quantile:quantile(0.4)
        permno    price            mv  yearmonth
8692     10137  30.8750  5.742132e+06     198303
```

Some code that I've tried:

```
q20=data.groupby("yearmonth")["mv"].quantile(0.2)
q40=data.groupby("yearmonth")["mv"].quantile(0.4)
q60=data.groupby("yearmonth")["mv"].quantile(0.6)
q80=data.groupby("yearmonth")["mv"].quantile(0.8)


for yearmonth,y in data.groupby(["yearmonth"]):
    data_q20=y[y["mv"]<=q20[yearmonth]]
    data_q40=y[y["mv"]<=q40[yearmonth]]
    data_q40=data_q40[data_q40["mv"]>q20[yearmonth]]
    data_q60=y[y["mv"]<=q60[yearmonth]]
    data_q60=data_q60[data_q60["mv"]>q40[yearmonth]]
    data_q80=y[y["mv"]>q60[yearmonth]]
    data_q80=data_q80[data_q80["mv"]<=q80[yearmonth]]
    data_q100=y[y["mv"]>q80[yearmonth]]
```

I am not sure how to map the yearmonth of "mv" with respect to the quantile one using apply. Any hint on that?

The ultimate goal of this sorting is to calculate the mean return in each yearmonth.

Comment: Since your dataframes' data is cut off, its hard to give you a specific answer.  Can you provide a more simplified example of what you need?  Try breaking your dataframes down into 4 columns each with 5 rows a peice.  Then see what happens.  If its not working on that scale, it won't on the larger scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to use cut or qcut to get your desired results. Cut will create evenly spaced ranges while qcut will create an even number of items per bin. Qcut is more consistent with quantiles.

Here's my code:

```
#Recreate your dataset
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'permno':[10057, 10137,10153, 10225, 10233, 10241],
        'price':[18.125, 23.75,9.75, 45.875,57.625, 30.875],
        'mv':[7.898875e+04, 1.130191e+06, 1.226550e+05,2.530740e+06,1.670894e+06, 5.742132e+06 ],
        'yearmonth':[198301, 198301,198302,198302, 198303,198303]
    },
    index=[1752, 4732, 6144, 7869, 8267, 8692]
)

#Create a column for the classification. 
df['Quantiles']= df.groupby(['yearmonth'])['mv'].transform(
    lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5, labels=(0.2, 0.4,.6,.8,1.0))
)
```

From here, you could filter the transactions. I think that the dataset you provided is too small but on a larger dataset, this code should work fine.